# How to enable "Append Changes to Existing Text" on a multiple line of text column, programmatically?

Tags: multiple-lines-of-text

I created programmatically a list and a column. This column is a multiple line of text. I would like to also enable the option "Append Changes to Existing Text" programmatically. How to do that?

```
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                // check if list exists
                SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(listTitle);

                if (list == null)
                {
                    SPListCollection listCollection = web.Lists;

                    // create new list
                    Guid gd = listCollection.Add(listTitle, "", SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
                    //listCollection[gd].Update();

                    // get new created archive log list and add columns
                    list = listCollection[gd];

                    // enable versioning
                    list.EnableVersioning = true;          

                    list.Fields.Add("Log", SPFieldType.Note, false);

                    SPFieldMultiLineText logField = list.Fields.GetField("Log") as SPFieldMultiLineText;
                    // DO SOMETHING TO ALLOW APPEND CHANGES TO EXISTING TEXT
                    // save columns
                    list.Update();
               }
           }
```

Comment: It can be set, but you'd need to enable versioning on the list first before enabling that property on the column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:    `logField.AppendOnly = true;`

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldmultilinetext.appendonly.aspx).